# Calling function when if statement fails in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

Fairly new to this.  I have a function called "getInformation" with 3 ajax functions in it.

When the if statement fails in the success function shown here, I want to call/trigger the "getInformation" function, but I don't know which selector to use (or if I even need a selector).

```
success: function(serverResponse){
           if(serverResponse.length>1){
               try{
                   var searchResultsHTML='';
                   console.log(serverResponse);

                   $("#searchResults").append(searchResultsHTML);
                }catch (ex) {
                      console.error(ex);
                      $("#searchResults").text("An error occurred processing the data");
                }
            } else{
                   //run the other ajax calls
                   $.fn.getInfortmation();
            }
```

Comment: Is `getInformation` function related to element manipulation function or normal function. If it is normal function just use `callback` approach or jquery `promise` approach. Or can add `getInformation` function also here, so that is clear to understand.

Comment: So what doesn't work? You've already got a call to the function there, though the name is misspelled.

Comment: i don't know how you're declaring the function but i don't think you need the `$.fn.` , just call `getInformation()`

Comment: It's hard to help you debug a function we can't see the source code of.

Comment: I just used getInformation();

Comment: It works! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may be misunderstanding the meaning of the `$` in jQuery. This is actual just a shorthand or alias of sorts for the word `jQuery`, a class (or some JS equivalent holder) that contains all of the functions in the library.

Just because you are writing code within a jQuery callback (the `success` handler), does not mean you need to use only `jQuery` functions. You are free to use your own code, and I believe that `getInformation` is one of your defined functions.

To solve the problem, call the function without the jQuery `$` like `fn.getInformation`. I assume that your function is within a different object called `fn`. If not, remove the `fn` as well.

As far as selectors go, thats a different topic. Those are used to easily select and work with HTML elements on the page in your code. jQuery is very useful for doing this, but not all jQuery functions involve selectors/DOM. For example, in this case it appears you might be doing some AJAX which directly doesn't have anything to do with manipulating page elements but rather is about communicating data to a server.